# Google Places API, GMSAutocomplete search only for City, Country iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, gmsautocomplete

I have setup the Google GMSAutocomplete like so:

```
private func setupAutocompleteWithTextFieldController() {
    let kTextFieldTop: CGFloat = searchField.frame.origin.y
    let kTextFieldHeight: CGFloat = 44.0
    let kContentRectTop = kTextFieldTop + kTextFieldHeight

    contentRect = CGRectMake(0, kContentRectTop, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - kTextFieldHeight)

    searchField.autocorrectionType = .No
    searchField.returnKeyType = .Done
    searchField.clearButtonMode = .WhileEditing
    searchField.addTarget(self, action: "searchFieldTextFieldEditingChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    searchField.delegate = self

    tableDataSource = GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource()
    tableDataSource.delegate = self

    resultsController = UITableViewController(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    resultsController.tableView.delegate = tableDataSource
    resultsController.tableView.dataSource = tableDataSource
}
```

and also implemented the delegates, `UITextFieldDelegate`, `GMSAutocompleteTableDataSourceDelegate` and it's working great. However, I would like to limit the search to locality, administrativeArea and country. e.g. I don't want it to search for 'Places'. let

I know there is the filter object; however, how do I apply it to my use?  Any ideas?

`filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()`, `filter.type = GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter.City`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [autocompleteFilter](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_table_data_source.html#a85556609095854867e3f483f3dd10394) field of the `GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I was trying the 'filter' property with no luck. So much for NOT reading the docs.

Answer (score 0):

[Google auto complete api](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#call_gmsplacesclient)

```
func placeAutocomplete() { //Call function from your search editing method
 let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
 filter.type = GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter.City
  //"YOUR_SEARCH_DATA" Ex. Sydney Oper
 //Uou will get data for  city sydney
 placesClient?.autocompleteQuery("YOUR_SEARCH_DATA", bounds: nil, filter: filter, callback: { (results, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if let error = error {
    println("Autocomplete error \(error)")
 }
  for result in results! {
  if let result = result as? GMSAutocompletePrediction {
    println("Result \(result.attributedFullText) with placeID \(result.placeID)")
  }
  }
 })
}
```

Comment: Your answer is to get place predictions programmatically. I am using the place api widget (top of the same page as your link) and would like to filter it with the widget. Any ideas?